# What setups work to trigger a Profoto B1 and Canon 600EX-RT Speedlights together from canon body

Tags: canon, flash, off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash, strobes

Given a Profoto B1, a Profoto AIR Remote TTL-C, and some Canon 600EX-RT , what configurations work with triggering these items together.

Additional items are allowed (slave triggers, pocket wizards, yungnuo etc).

Preference would be the B1 is still triggered via the AIR TTL, ok if the 600EX's are manual, nice to have is if power levels of 600's can still be adjusted via a ST-E3 or other 600EX.

My research sofar has suggested:

- Air Remote in Hotshoe triggering B1, and something like a "USYK-3A Wireless Hot Shoe Flash Remote Slave Trigger for Canon Flasher" attached to the 600EX-RT as optical slaves.

**Update**

- I had some generic wireless hot shoe flash triggers given to try, they worked very intermittently, mayby 1 in 3 shots they fired, this was with direct sight of the triggering flash they would not fire, either they are faulty or just work this way.  So as per accepted answer going to order the Yongnuo's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, obviously, the simplest (but most expensive) path would be to get Profoto Air Syncs and hook them up as receivers to your 600EX-RTs, but that's a lot of expense to have manual-only triggers for your 600EX-RTs.

However, your best bet is to sandwich a [Yongnuo YN-622C](http://flashhavoc.com/yn622c_review/) (TTL radio trigger with a full TTL passthrough hotshoe) between the camera and the Profoto Air Remote TTL-C, and have other YN-622C units as receivers on the 600EX-RTs. While you won't get the post-2012 RT features (groups D&E, ID codes, shutter release, etc.), you will have remote power control, eTTL-II, HSS, and something similar to Gr mode with the 600EX-RTs, and you'll still have full control of the B1 from the TTL-C trigger. From a [Profoto blog comment](http://www.profoto.com/blog/off-camera-flash/camera-flash-faq/#comment-257247):

> I am new to profoto and just bought my B1 last week and used it on my first wedding. It managed to set everything out in reception and control both the canon 580 and B1 on camera/trigger. My set up goes like this:
>
> B1 as main light shaped by an umbrella, triggered by TTL remote, which is locked on the hotshoe of the Yuongnuo YN622C TTL trigger.
>
> The YN622C is then mounted on my 1Dx hotshoe.
>
> The Canon 580EXii is used as the rim/side light, mounted on YN622 and secured on a light stand.
>
> 1) you can control both lights using TTL since the yongnuo trigger also supports it. Or you could manually control power in camera menu(this is how you adjust output of speedlite using that trigger.
>
> 2) when you don’t wanna use light at all just turn off the YN622 trigger and the camera will revert your shutter speed if it’s above 1/250! The AirTTL trigger bug is temporarily fixed!
>   ...

Chances are good that any eTTL radio triggers with a TTL passthrough hotshoe would also work for this (e.g., Phottix Odins or PocketWizard MiniTT1).

Comment: All things I considered as well, the problem being that there can only be one master in the eTTL system (not singling Canon out here; AFAIK it would cause a problem an everybody's system) and you'd want the Air TTL remote to be it if the B1 is the key light. Dumb triggering is all you'd get for the speedlights with the Air Syncs; the B1 won't send the optical signals for IR mode, and the Air TTL-C system "speaks" eTTL, but it doesn't "speak" Canon RT. Which means there's room for an Air Sync TTL, since you just know the speedlight is going to be the thing flying 14' in the air.

Comment: @user35658, I've edited the hell out of my answer (removed the YNE3-RX speculation and optical trigger use), since I found a comment where someone says that sandwiching a YN-622C between the camera and the Profoto TTL transmitter works for full control of both the Canon speedlights and the B1.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that if you use a Yongnuo YN-622C, you will be able to trigger your canon speedlights.  The setup that I have is 1 Profoto TTL Air remote, 2 Yongnuo YN-622C, 1 430EX II flash, 1 B1.  One of the Yongnuo goes between the camera and the Profoto Air remote.  The other on the speedlight.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that I can think of that would work (with manual control of the 600EXs power levels) would be the [Cactus V6 trigger system](http://www.gadgetinfinity.com/cactus-wireless-flash-transceiver-v6.html). (Gadget Infinity is the retail arm of the company that makes it, in case you're wondering where the link is going.) Anything you can use to get a "dumb" trigger signal to the transmitting V6 unit will do, which would include a passthru eTTL hotshoe adapter with a PC terminal if your camera's body doesn't have a PC terminal (or the terminal is disabled when something's living on the hot shoe) or an optical pick-up like a Wein Peanut. The V6 unit itself can then be used to remotely control the power levels of slave 600EX units mounted on receiving units. And no, it's not cheap; you may find it more cost-effective to use an alternate flash system (Yongnuo YN560III/IV used in conjunction with a YN560-TXc controller or with one of the IVs used as a controller, or the Godox system, or what have you) unless you already have a whole passel of Canon flashes to hand.