# Can I mix the Profoto off-camera flash system with other Nikon flashes?

Tags: nikon, off-camera-flash, ttl, wireless-flash, profoto

If I get a **Profoto B1**, from what I read they do `TTL` and they have their own AirRmote trigger which is all important for me ( I do want Remote trigger and `HSS` and `TTL`)
But now my question is how about the rest of `Nikon SB-910` flashes that I have? Will that remote be able to also control my `SB-910s`? so basically a setup of main light coming from one Profoto B1 and other lights coming from SB-910s ? All TTL and HSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not directly. The Air Remote triggers have no way to attach to a flash foot (i.e., there are no hotshoe receiver units in the system).  On the Canon side of the fence, there are folks who are sandwiching TTL radio triggers (YN-622, Pixel King, etc.) between the camera hotshoe and the Air Remote, and achieving TTL/HSS with speedlights that way, but with the gear as-is, I don't think it's possible.

While it's not in any way an equivalent to the Profoto system, you might want to consider looking at Phottix.  The [Phottix Indra](http://flashhavoc.com/phottix-indra-500-ttl-now-available/) is a strobe that can be run off a battery pack, that is TTL/HS capable and has a Phottix Odin receiver built-in.  And the Phottix Odins are TTL-capable speedlight radio triggers, so you can use speedlights and the Indra in combination and still have FP/HSS, iTTL, and remote power control over all your lights.

Comment: Can still run Nikon SB-910s as optical slaves? But will lose everything, they will be in manual mode. Correct?

Comment: As manual-only SU-4 slaves, probably (don't know if the Profoto preflash for TTL would muck things up); as CLS slaves, no.

Comment: I asked B&H , they said No  unless it is optical slave, Or use it on Manual with PocketWizards. If it is the TTL version of PocketWizards then we get HSS too but no TTL.

Comment: @user1899082 It works on the Canon side with YN-622C triggers. See: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60274/what-setups-work-to-trigger-a-profoto-b1-and-canon-600ex-rt-speedlights-together

Answer (score 1):

Can put the Profoto AirTTL on camera hot shoe to TTL and HSS the Profotos and also connect whatever other flash to PokcetWizard, Attached one PocketWizard to SyncPort of the camera.